# How to manage the style of citation quote in latex?

Tags: bibtex, citing

Here shown an example of my problem

```
\documentclass{article}

\bibstyle{numbers}

\begin{document}

ABCD\cite{Marcastel:1621583}


\bibliography{mybib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}



\end{document}
```

What I got is like this:
[image: What I got]

I just wondering how to mange the color of the number inside the citation quotes

```
ABCD [1(colored)]
```

Comment: You have to change the citation style, but without knowing what style you are using and with which package it is difficult to give you an answer. Please show a mwe.

Comment: The default citation format depends on the citation package you load and possibly also on the citation style you load. Please show us a compilable example document that shows how you generate your bibliography and citations (an MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).

Comment: Unfortunately, "XeLatex and bibtex" is by far not enough detail to be able to help you. Your best bet is to show us a short example document we can compile to see what you have at the moment.

Comment: Hi @moewe I have edited my question, thanks.

Comment: What color do you want for the citation call-out numerals? Do you maybe want the numerals to be colored hyperlinks to the corresponding entries in the formatted biblliography?

Comment: @Mico blue or green or somehow. And the numbers are already hyperlinks to the corresponding entries in bibliography, what I want is just make these number colored.

Comment: @springcc - So, please do reveal *how*, i.e., with which options, you load the `hyperref` package? Does the document feature a `\hypersetup` instruction? If so, what are its arguments? Please feel free to edit your posting to backfill these important, but so far missing, pieces of information.